# Add columns to SYBUNT report

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

We run CiviCRM 5.20.2 on Joomla 3.9.15

We use Reports - Donation Reports - Sybunt
We need to be able to select in the Columns area:
•   Nickname
•   Do not mail / contact
•   Deceased
•   Postal Greeting

Is a custom report necessary? If so how do I use the SYBUNT report as a template to copy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [hook_civicrm_alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/)(Instead of making copy of existing report and adding code) to add columns or filters to any report in $vars for $varType == 'Column'.

Comment: Do you have an example you could link to?